# Column abc does not belong to table?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am iterating a DataTable in my C# code. I try to get the contents using of a column named "columnName" of row named "row" using -

```
object value = row["ColumnName"];
```

I get this error -

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. 
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: Column 'FULL_COUNT' does not belong to table .    at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)

How is this possible ? My SQL query/result set has a column by that name and the query even runs in management studio.

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: Please show how you're querying the database to start with. You might also want to look over all the columns in the table to work out what *has* been picked up.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Okay. I will need some more time to replicate the problem in an example table. Will do it shortly.

Comment: If ColumnName is the iteration parameter, you need to put it as `row[ColumnName]`. the way you are doing it, in each iteration it is looking for a column named ColumnName in your columns.

Comment: As the error message, the problem is **"no have any column named `FULL_COUNT`"**, so I assume that you have such this line `row["FULL_COUNT"]` in your code, don't you? Otherwise, please provide us a full code.

Comment: Referrring to wrong table...stupid of me. There were multiple rows and datatables with similar names.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am guessing your code is iteration supposed to be something like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
        object value = row[col.ColumnName];
    }
}
```

If this is the case, `row["ColumnName"]` in each iteration looks for the same column with name `ColumnName` which obviously does not exists in your table.

The correct way is `row[ColumnName]` or `row[col.ColumnName]` in iteration above

Answer (score 2):

Try this, make sure your column name is same

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("abc", typeof(string));
    
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["abc"]="";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not write Gridview column names instead of Database column names.

```
dataGridViewEmployeeClass.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["write the Database Column names"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on my c# code, using a dataset which I had successfully initialized and populated with data from the DB.

So my return set was:

> data = new Byte[0];
>
> data = (Byte[])(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["systemLogo_img"]);

Of course the error was in t finding the column 'systemLogo_img'.

I noted that you simply do NOT have to call /qualify the column name. So the correction is:

> data = new Byte[0];
>
> data = (Byte[])(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);

Simply put: use "ItemArray" at position.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the column exists in the DataRow before accessing the value the following block can help...

```
if (dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains("theColumnName"))
{
    // do work
    string text = string.Empty;
    if (dataRow["theColumnName"] != System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        text = Convert.ToString(dataRow["theColumnName"]);
    }
}
```

If it doesn't exist and it needs to be added to the data table you can add the column using @Karthick Ganesan's example

```
// add a column
dataTable.Columns.Add("theColumnName", typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was very basic to fix.

I was querying with a specific column name rather than `Select *` (i.e. `Select Title`). Beginner's error but happens to everyone.

Answer (score -5):

I had same issue  was trying to pass two different keys for same product.

```
  item.Product = SqlHelper.GetSafeString(dr, "ProductName");
  item.Product = SqlHelper.GetSafeString(dr, "Product");
```